# Move semantics in dependency injection

Tags: c++11, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, move-semantics, hypodermic

Is it possible or helpful to employ move semantics when preforming constructor injection?

If so, is Hypodermic setup to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypodermic can *automatically* use move constructors, it can spare you the cost of updating the reference counter of your dependencies.
You have nothing special to do but provinding a move constructor of the concerned object.

For now, Hypodermic cannot resolve an object providing both version of its constructor (move vs non-move), that is, the compiler will complain about ambigous call.